# How to pass only those items in request body that have checkboxes checked in node.js and ejs templating engine

Tags: node.js, ejs

```
<form action="/attendence" method="post">
  <ul>
    <% for (let user of usersdata) { %>
    <li class="listItems">
      <a class="names" href="/users/<%=user.id%>"> <%=user.username%> </a>
      <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" />      
    </li>
    <% } %>
  </ul>
</form>
```

I want that only those names are passed to `/attendence` api's request body that have checkboxes checked. I am working with nodejs and ejs templating engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can add name and value attributes to checkbox input so that it can be passed when user submits the form:

```
<form action="/attendence" method="post">
  <ul class="listItems">
    <% for (let user of usersdata) { %>
      <div class="div">
        <li >
          <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="name" value= <%=user.username%> > 
          <label><a class="names" href="/users/<%=user.id%>"> <%=user.username%></a></label>
        </li>  
      </div>
    <% } %>
  </ul> 
  <div class="container"><button class="btn">SUBMIT</button></div>
</form>
```

the `/attendence` api looks like this:

```
exports.addPresentUsers = (req, res, next) => {
  const presentUsers = req.body.name
  console.log(req.body.name)
  res.render('attendence', {
    presentUsers:presentUsers,
  });
}
```